# SQL report has duplicate lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query

```
select
    s.[AR SALE Customer ID],  
    d.[AR SALED Item Id],  
    d.[AR SALED Item Category],  
    d.[AR SALED Print Item UPC],  
    abs(d.[ar saled unit price]) as 'Unit Price',  
    sum(case 
           when d.[AR SALED Qty Shipped] > 0 and s.[AR SALE Document Type] like 'invoice'  
             then d.[AR SALED Qty Shipped]  
           else 0  
        end) as 'QTY Invoiced',  
    sum(case 
           when d.[AR SALED Qty Shipped] > 0 and s.[AR SALE Document Type] like 'invoice'  
             then d.[AR SALED Item Total]  
             else 0 
        end) as 'Sales at Wholesale',  
    sum(case 
           when d.[AR SALED Qty Shipped] < 0 and s.[AR SALE Document Type] like 'return'  
             then d.[AR SALED Qty Shipped]  
             else 0 
        end) as 'QTY returned',  
    sum(case 
           when d.[AR SALED Qty Shipped] < 0 and s.[AR SALE Document Type] like 'return'  
             then d.[AR SALED Item Total]  
             else 0 
        end) as 'Returns at Wholesale',  
    sum(case 
           when s.[AR SALE Document Type] in ('invoice','return')   
              then d.[AR SALED Qty Shipped]  
              else 0 
        end) as 'Net Units',  
    sum(case 
           when s.[AR SALE Document Type] in ('invoice','return')   
             then d.[AR SALED Item Total]  
             else 0
        end) as 'Net Wholesale',
    s.[AR SALE Salesperson]  
from 
    [ar sales] s  
inner join 
    [ar customer] c on (c.[ar cust customer id] = s.[ar sale customer id])  
inner join 
    [AR Sales Detail] d on (d.[AR SALED Document #] = s.[AR SALE Document #])  
where 
    [AR SALE Date] >= '1/1/2015' and [AR SALE Date] < '2/1/2015'  
group by 
    s.[ar sale customer id], d.[AR SALED Item Id], d.[AR SALED Item Category],  
    d.[AR SALED Print Item UPC], d.[ar saled unit price], s.[AR SALE Salesperson]  
order by 
    s.[AR sale customer ID],d.[AR SALED Item Id]
```

but i keep getting sales and returns on a different line like the following

```
ID      Item        Group           UPC            Price  QTY  Wholesale QTY ret 

300209  ACSC00042   1400-HARDWARE   853803000421    7.79    6   46.74   0   0.00    6   46.74  

300209  ACSC00042   1400-HARDWARE   853803000421    7.79    0   0.00    -2  -15.58  -2  -15.58
```

it is the same item with sales and returns on different lines. Any ideas?

Comment: use `sum` on `abs(d.[ar saled unit price])` and remove `d.[ar saled unit price]` from `group by`

Comment: That did it! Thanks!